# AEM Rules for Sonarqube does not support Java 1.8

Tags: azure, gradle, sonarqube

Our application on Azure started recently throwing the following error while performing a SonarQube build with Gradle:

> The plugin [aemrules] does not support Java 1.8.0_265

We are not ready now for a Java upgrade, so is there any way we can get rid of this error?

Is it correct that it is not SonarQube actually but a plugin of it (AEM Rules) that causes this error?

Comment: Downgrade AEM-rules to version [1.0](https://github.com/Cognifide/AEM-Rules-for-SonarQube/releases) maybe?

Comment: What is the solution of this?

Comment: @MehulParmar: I added my answer below, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

We ended up upgrading our whole environment. With Java 11 and recent versions of all plugins, there was no problem.
So I am not sure this would have been solvable with Java 1.8.